# Sharing a component between multiple modules, without app.module.ts file

Tags: angular

I have a component MenuComponent which I want to use in multiple modules.

Here is the first module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
imports: [SharedModule],
})
export class TestModule implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const ngElement = createCustomElement(TestComponent, { injector: this.injector, });
    customElements.get('my-test') || customElements.define('my-test', ngElement);
  }
}
```

Here is the second:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
imports: [SharedModule],
})
export class Test2Module implements DoBootstrap {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const ngElement = createCustomElement(TestComponent, { injector: this.injector, });
    customElements.get('my-test2') || customElements.define('my-test2', ngElement);
  }
}
```

They are almost the same, pretty simple. I created a SharedModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MenuComponent],
  declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
  exports: [ MenuComponent
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

I don't have an app.module.ts file, instead I have a module for each of the elements and I build each of them separately. How can I use the MenuComponent in multiple modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply import `SharedModule` in `TestModule` and `Test2Module` module, the only requirement is that `MenuComponent` is exported in the `SharedModule`.

You don't need to declare `MenuComponent` in these modules, only in `SharedModule`.

It works in the way that all imported exports of parent modules are accessible in imported and declared children.

So if you don't have a parent module like AppModule - simply import your dependency in every module where you wan to use it.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    MenuComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    MenuComponent,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
})
export class TestModule {
  // ...
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
})
export class Test2Module {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I already have MenuComponent exported in SharedModule. If i import the SharedModule in Test and Test2 I still get the error The Component 'MenuComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

Comment: Please check my edited question in which I implemented your suggestion.

Comment: you don't need to declare `MenuComponent` in them, only import `SharedModule`

Comment: And can I apply the same solution to pipes, directives and services?

Comment: Yes, simply export them in the module that declares them and import this module where you need them.

Comment: After I did that, I get an error in the MenuComponent saying that menu.component.html: Can't bind to 'ngStyle' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: import `CommonModule` in the `SharedModule`

Comment: I added it i imports:[CommonModule] and still I get the same error

Comment: That's weird, https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle, perhaps try to export it too, but usually its import is enough.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can you check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193972/cant-bind-to-ngstyle-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div-when-commonmodu

Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: Ah, so do you want to use menu inside of bootstrap? then try to import CommonModule in the Test modules too.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain in the butt, but I changed it and still get the same error. I updated the other question.

Comment: No worries :) might you create a stackbliz example of it? I think we are close but miss a small detail.

Comment: Also I would say let's mark this question as answered if it fits and continue discussion in the new one with its problem.